# C# WinApi Without StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, winapi, marshalling, stringbuilder

Can I use WinApi functions that have `out` string-parameter without StringBuilder ? If yes, how ? Or is that the easiest way to retrieve strings from WinApi ?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint FormatMessage(uint flags, IntPtr source, uint messageID, int languageID, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, string[] arguments);

// I wished I could use it with just a string
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint FormatMessage(uint flags, IntPtr source, uint messageID, int languageID, ref [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string buffer, int bufferSize, string[] arguments);
```

*(My function is probably buggy. I'm not sure)*

Comment: Why would you want to get rid of the StringBuilder? First figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I would like to use string directly instead of a helper class. Is that a crazy wish ?

Comment: Yes, it's crazy. A `string` is by definition and by design _immutable_` . And after the call all you need is `parameterSb.ToString()`

Comment: No, you're wrong. My wish is not crazy. It's just ignorant. ^^ Most people wish that life and work was easier.